# SQL Errors when running Rails 3.2.19 with Ruby 2.1.5 with Passenger 4.0.57

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, passenger, ruby-2.1

Currently our Rails app is running on Ruby 1.9.3 and Passenger 3.0.19. But when we upgraded Ruby to version 2.1.5 and Passenger to 4.0.57 the application started generating weird sql queries similar to the following

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: [34816] syntax error: improper query string termination: SELECT (End of query)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: [8192] Relation not found: no such relation ": SELECT ` (End of query)
Mysql2::Error: [32768] Translate error: SQL-ERROR: unable to resolve relation "": SELECT agents.* FROM agents WHERE ``.id = 22241082 LIMIT 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: [32769] Unknown column: SQL-ERROR: unable to resolve column "agents.: SELECT  agents.* FROM agents WHERE agents.` (end of query)
One update query with where clause "0 = 0"
```

We need help with the following questions

1. Is ruby 2.1.5 compatible with Rails 3.2.19?
2. Can this issue be related to the ruby or Passenger upgrade or is it a bug in our application that is causing this? How can we go about debugging
   this?

Comment: the problem seems to be with the sql query, can you show the table structure for your table and what/how are you retrieving it?

Comment: Ruby 2.0.x is as high as Rails 3.2.x was tested with.  I've had no luck getting Rails 3.2.x to work with Ruby 2.1.x.  You may need to downgrade Ruby to 2.0.x.

Comment: @infused we tested our application with the following combinations. Ruby 2.1.x & Passenger 4.x, Ruby 1.9.x & Passenger 4.x, Ruby 2.1.x & passenger 3.x, Ruby 1.9.x & Passenger 3.x. Among these we were able to reproduce these errors only when had Passenger 4.x. Can you please let me know what web server you were using when trying Rails 3.2.x with Ruby 2.1. Also what error you ran into when trying to do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally figured out that the issue to be related to some old gems which was part of our code base. Upgrading them to be compatible with Ruby 2.x fixed the issue.

Comment: Do you know which gems were causing trouble? I am currently suspecting the composite_primary_keys gem.

Comment: i think, in our case, nokogiri was causing the above errors.